# Using animate scroll along with another ahref function

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have implemented this script at the bottom of my webpage in order to get to get that nice slow animate effect when somebody clicks on a link in navigation that leads to some anchor part of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 1500);
return false;
});
</script>
```

However I also have gallery that uses data filter to arrange several images on the same page.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".artwork">Artwork</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography">Photography</a></li>
```

The problem is that gallery stops arranging images on click when I implement the javascript scroll animate code.

I have tried changing html,body into header since that is the ID of div where navigation is located. Also I tried using class name of div where navigation is located instead of html,body $('html, body').animate

Is there any way to have both functions working? Can I somehow limit javascript to applying animate scroll to this part of the page. So to initiate animate scroll only for this part of the page, so that gallery can work also:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#team" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">Team</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact1" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">Contact</a></li>
                </ul><!--//nav-->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the scroll click handler only to the `a` tags that you want to trigger the scroll functionality, by using the selector `.nav-item a`. This will prevent your `data-filter` links from triggering the scroll.

```
$('.nav-item a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // do this instead of return false (note the e param)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
  }, 1500);
});
```

Other notes in general:

- You are using the id `anchor1` for multiple elements. A given `id` should only appear once on the entire page. Class names, on the other hand, can be used more than once.
- Take the event parameter passed into your click handler in order to prevent the `a` tags from firing their default handlers. (Do this in place of `return false;` See the comment in the code above.)